# Regular expression, plus vs asterisk

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a String with a number in it:

dfdf00023546546

I want to get only the number:

```
(0*)(\d+) works
(0*)(\d*) doesn't work
(0*)(\d*$) works
```

if plus means 1 or more and asterisk means 0 or more, isn't * suppose to catch more than +? why does adding the $ sign makes it work?

Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem

Comment: All versions will definitely work (if used properly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your problem is with `g` mode which is probably not set. If you set this global mode you will see [expected substring is matched](https://regex101.com/r/t7xnPL/1).

This `(0*)(\d*)` matches but returns more than two groups in a `g` mode because both patterns are `*`-quantified which includes *zero-length matches*.

`+` quantifier denotes at least one occurrence of preceding token so it looks for something which its existence is a must. Having that said, it doesn't return zero-length matches.

Your third try `(0*)(\d*$)` works the same as `+` quantifier for the reason that zero-length matches couldn't occur earlier than meeting digits that meet the end of input string. With this regex however, there is a zero-length match at the end when `g` mode is on.

Answer (score 0):

This might be hard to understand, but your regex will be somewhat as follows:

- `(0*)(\d+)` will return a single match `00023546546`.
- `(0*)(\d*$)`
  will return 2 matches `00023546546` and
  end of string `{empty}`. The second match is because it has to check for zero or
  more ocurrences of 0 - which can be `{empty}` and zero or more
  occurrences of numbers between 0-9 - which again can be `{empty}` and the end of string check.
- `(0*)(\d*)` on the other hand checks at 6 different positions - before each of the letters, because technically a match can be an `{empty}` according to your regex. One non-empty match which will return your numbers and one end of string match which is again empty.

Answer (score 0):

Please remember that regex will not only match characters, but also produce 0-length matches.

`(0*)(\d*)` in fact *works*, it's just that it matches the stuff you want *plus* some empty matches:

```
[ '', '', '', '', '00023546546', '' ]
```

See those 0-length matches?

Now I'll explain why those 0-length matches are there. Your regex says that there should be 0 or more `0`s, followed by 0 or more digits. This means that it can match 0 `0`s and 0 digits, doesn't it? So the space between every character is matched because that "substring" has exactly 0 `0`s and 0 digits!

By the way `(0*)(\d*$)` will only work if the match is at the end of the string.